# How to disable middle click + drag with FlashGot?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have the [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/) extension installed in Firefox. When I middle click on a link and then accidentally move the mouse before releasing the button, FlashGot captures the link and the file gets downloaded in my download manager. I don't want this behavior, how can I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's not “middle click + drag”, it's “middle click + drag downwards”.

To disable it, set `flashgot.gesture` and `flashgot.gesture.feedback` to `false` in `about:config`.

Source: [*How to disable "Middle Click + Drag Down" hotkey?* at InformAction forums](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8340)